# た＋ではないか　or た＋のではないか can someone enlighten me?

Tags: translation, syntax, jlpt

I encountered a question in my JLPT n1 practice book , and I got really confused because I was sure my answer was right but when I look at the answer sheet the answer is really far from what I have learned so far.

the question was

```
その日、私はホームに入ってきた電車に飛び乗った。ところが、電車は反対方向に走り始めた（　　　　　　）。
私は電車の行き先を確かめなかったことを後悔した。
１．ではない
２．ではないか
３．のではない
４．のではないか
```

my answer was 4 but it says on the book its 2. Up until now I know that I have to put の after verb+た or verb +る in order to place ではないか.

and the sentence "私はホームに入ってきた電車に飛び乗った。" really confuse me 
Does it mean " I took the train that just arrived" ?

can someone help me with this one?

Comment: similar question but , I still need to know when to use the right pattern in answering this types of question and I believe there is still someone that can clarify this point.

Comment: Unfortunately, there aren't really any rules behind it. You just have to think about the meaning behind each one. The other options may not make sense in context.

Comment: Actually, there is.....FYI:[link](http://japanese-revision.tumblr.com/post/37834450990/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B-i-think-it-might) I am sorry I will be busy today and there is a clear difference...may be you can check **why** just by reefing through the link. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, There is a huge research only for the **collocation** のではないか [link](http://dspace.wul.waseda.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2065/31355/1/WasedaNihongoKenkyu_17_Konishi.pdf#search=%27%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B+%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%27), Here, のではないか　is dealt as the collocation of ( negation (　ない　) of のだ + questioning closing particle か　）．　And it is said it became to denote to "demand the further information" and then it became "I think..., I guess...." as I uploaded above.

Comment: On the other hand, ではないか　is also the collocation, ( = case marking particle で　+ same は,　negation ない　+　closing particle to denote the utterance か　), but it does not mean the negation [link](http://catalog.lib.kyushu-u.ac.jp/handle/2324/21903/p067.pdf#search=%27%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B+%E5%90%A6%E5%AE%9A%27), but in turn to become to denote the confirmation or utterance. So that 2 is correct. Since the question wants you to make a sentence "But the train has begun to start running the other way!". I voted to reopen but unfortunately this week I will be hilariously busy,

Comment: so should the question be open, I wish somebody can help you with more information, personally. Good luck.

Comment: 参考までに・・・http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1298540217

Comment: ではないか="lo and behold" という人もいます-> http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/%E9%9B%BB%E8%BB%8A%E3%81%AF%E5%8F%8D%E5%AF%BE%E6%96%B9%E5%90%91%E3%81%AB%E8%B5%B0%E3%82%8A%E5%A7%8B%E3%82%81%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B.2532380/

Comment: @choco I never imagined someone will post an exact question but that was a relief knowing someone got confused by this  similar question. Thanks btw.

Comment: @kentarotomono your links are useful btw , I managed to find out the difference between +ではないか　and +のではないか

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `[verb] + ではないか` is an exclamatory phrase which denotes the speaker's surprise or accusation.

> [*]電車は反対方向に走り始めた**ではない**。 (Ungrammatical)
>
> 電車は反対方向に走り始めた**ではないか**。
>   **(To my surprise,)** The train started to run in the opposite direction!
>
> 電車は反対方向に走り始めた**のではない**。
>   It is not that the train started to run in the opposite direction.
>
> 電車は反対方向に走り始めた**のではないか**。
>   **(I wonder,)** Didn't this train start to run in the opposite direction?

4 is incorrect, because the following sentence says 後悔した, which indicates he realized (rather than just wondered) something bad in the second sentence.